# Populate table using AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to fill html table with data from database using ajax.

Using PHP I generate this array:

```
[
    {
        "custom_id":"453",
        "name":"test",
        "barcode":"3234234",
        "grupa":"Служебна група",
        "quantity_type":"бр.",
        "quantity_number":"1",
        "obekt":"Служебен обект",
        "price_delivery":"0.00",
        "price_sale":"0.00"
    },
    {
        "custom_id":"2",
        "name":"asdasd",
        "barcode":"","grupa":
        "Служебна група",
        "quantity_type":"бр.",
        "quantity_number":"1",
        "obekt":"Служебен обект",
        "price_delivery":"0.00",
        "price_sale":"0.00"
    },
    {
        "custom_id":"4",
        "name":"Тутракан",
        "barcode":"",
        "grupa":"Служебна група",
        "quantity_type":"бр.",
        "quantity_number":"1",
        "obekt":"Служебен обект",
        "price_delivery":"0.00",
        "price_sale":"0.00"
    }
]
```

And this is the JS:

```
function loadTable() {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "generate_json/get_items_2.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
    data: {action: "load"},
    success: function (response) {
        //i don't know what exactly to put here
    }
});
  return false;
}
```

I probably need loop but how to get access to the elements of the array?

Comment: Using the browsers JS debugger look at what is returned in `response`

Comment: `response` will contain your data. Now you need to create some HTML table rows containing your data and insert them into your page. I'm pretty sure you can find tutorials already which will show you samples of that. And maybe take a AJAX tutorial if you don't even know how that `response` contains your data.

Comment: i get the array as response

Comment: If your page full url is like this `http://www.example.com/generate_json/get_items_2.php` then put your url like this `url: "/generate_json/get_items_2.php"`

Comment: Ok so write a loop and for each item, create a table row (assuming that's what you want), append the row to your table. Again, you can find examples of that process online in many places already. No need to re-invent the wheel here. Try it, if you get stuck with something practical (as opposed to not knowing where to start) then come back to us.

Comment: @Ashish that's not the issue. OP can get their data, the comment right above yours verifies that, although it seems they only just realised it, but there you go. Anyway your comment is not necessarily correct, it depends on the structure of the specific website. OP seems to be doing fine without the extra `/`

Comment: @ADyson Yeah, i know, the actual question is, that, he wants to loop the `response` in the `success` function. I just thought he might want to understand how to write the url more properly too, since he mentioned this `//Relative or absolute path to response.php file` in his question. Since someone else was answering for `response` part, i tried answering for `url` part. His above comment was not existing when i wrote & posted this. :-(

Comment: @Ashish "write the url more properly". Neither way is more proper. OP's version gets the URL relative to the current URL. Your version gets it relative to the site root. Two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `success` callback you've to loop through the returned array as `response` constructing the rows and append them to the table like :

```js
var response = [{
  "custom_id": "453",
  "name": "test",
  "barcode": "3234234",
  "grupa": "Служебна група",
  "quantity_type": "бр.",
  "quantity_number": "1",
  "obekt": "Служебен обект",
  "price_delivery": "0.00",
  "price_sale": "0.00"
}, {
  "custom_id": "2",
  "name": "asdasd",
  "barcode": "",
  "grupa": "Служебна група",
  "quantity_type": "бр.",
  "quantity_number": "1",
  "obekt": "Служебен обект",
  "price_delivery": "0.00",
  "price_sale": "0.00"
}, {
  "custom_id": "4",
  "name": "Тутракан",
  "barcode": "",
  "grupa": "Служебна група",
  "quantity_type": "бр.",
  "quantity_number": "1",
  "obekt": "Служебен обект",
  "price_delivery": "0.00",
  "price_sale": "0.00"
}];

$.each(response, function(index, obj) {
  var row = $('<tr>');
  row.append('<td>' + obj.custom_id + '</td>');
  row.append('<td>' + obj.name + '</td>');
  row.append('<td>' + obj.barcode + '</td>');
  row.append('<td>' + obj.grupa + '</td>');

  $('table').append(row)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>Custom id</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Barcode</td>
    <td>Grupa</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```